# Coldfusion ignores changes in file

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, coldfusion

Now I have used many versions of CF in a linux environment and never run into this issue, so I am guessing this might be a windows problem.

I can make changes to a file and reload the page in IE, and Coldfusion seems to ignore the changes and reload the page as is was.  I can refresh many times and then suddenly "Poof"  I see my changes!  And before you ask, yes I am sure that I am editing and looking at the same file.

I don't have caching turned on and it does not happen all the time.  Has anyone else run into a similar situation?

Thanks

Comment: Based on discussion here it sounds like IE caching. Try the following link: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/turn-internet-explorers-cache-off/

Answer (score 2):

You can try to disable any caching with headers and see if anything changes, something like this:

```
<cfset SendHeader("Expires", "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT") />
<cfset SendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0") />
<cfset SendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache") />
<cfset SendHeader("Last-Modified",  DateFormat(DateConvert("Local2UTC", Now()), "full") & " " & TimeFormat(DateConvert("Local2UTC", Now()), "HH:mm:ss")) & " GMT" />
```

I'm using this one to avoid caching AJAX requests in IE.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that `SendHeader` is a wrapper UDF:

```
<cffunction name="SendHeader" returntype="void" access="public" output="false" hint="Wrapper of cfheader tag">
    <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="true" hint="Header name">
    <cfargument name="value" type="string" required="true" hint="Header value">
    <cfheader name="#arguments.name#" value="#arguments.value#" />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Currently, I am having problems reproducing the error.  Its like it knew i was trying to fix it and it went and hid  ;D

Comment: CF doesn't recognize SendHeader, where is that coming from?

Comment: @Limey, I'm sorry -- this function name looks so natural that I forgot that it's just a wrapper. See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Is IE the one caching the page?  Try clearing your IE cache next time and see if that helps.  Also are you editing CFC files in a Framework like FW/1 that caches controllers and services?

Comment: Well, yes we are using IE, and I have found that closing the window and reopening helps resolve the issue, but i can't see how anything on the client side could stop the server from recompiling. and no, no sprecial frameworks, just me, a CF file, and coldfusion

Comment: I am betting that CF is recompiling the files, but IE is just caching them.  Try it again, with a change that you know will show an effect, but instead of exiting IE just try clearing your cache.  Tools -> Browsing History -> Delete leave default settings.

Answer (score 1):

The cache can be provided from many sources.

Did you tried with another browser ?
Are you using a framework providing cache (Like Coldbox/MachII if yes try a reset or deactivate the cache in dev environment) ?
Do you connect to your server trough a proxy ?

What kind of file are you changing (html/cfm/cfc) ?

@I_twitIT

Comment: I'm changing a cfm with no framework, just the CF server.  I haven't tried in another browser simply cause my company only uses IE

Comment: If you have tried to set IE cache off without results, it may be caused by your company's proxy. In this case, you can try connecting to the server bypassing the proxy. To do this, you can : edit your host file and add an exception in IE connection settings.

Comment: How can I turn the cache off on IE?  may only guess would be to give the browsing history 0 megs to play with???

Comment: Under IE8, under browser history, there's a setting for how often IE checks agains the server version.  Make sure this is set to always check.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said caching in CF wasn't a problem but you didn't say what type.

I have seen this happen in CF 9 when the Admin setting *Caching -> Trusted Cache* is ticked. It can also cache CFCs if *Component cache* is checked. Also ensure that *Save Class Files* is not checked.

A good way to check if it is CF that is caching is to clear the template / component cache via CF admin and see if that fixes it straight off.

Also you don't mention your CF version - but I'd ensure that you are up to date to 9.0.1.

Hope that helps!

PS: all this assumes the page is not being cached in IE - I presume the problem is happening in other browsers?

Comment: I wish it did, but this is happening in at least two version (6 and 9) and i don't having caching turned on.

Comment: Can you reproduce in different browsers? One way to check is to output some info to a log file each time the page is requested, and see if the log lines match your refreshes.

Comment: I forgot to state that it also sometimes just doesn't run the page, it just says leaves it as it was.  For example, i have a stored job i am changing around that sends out an email.  Sometimes after i make a change it reload really fast, but it won't send the email.

Comment: Well that sounds like the server side script is not running. Are you sure that it's not being cached on the client-side? Try calling your URL with a different URL signature each time, e.g. `http://domain.com/yourScript.cfm?1234` and then `http://domain.com/yourScript.cfm?4567` etc - if it works every time it's almost certainly client-side caching.

Comment: I'm not running anything that the client side can cache.  Client side can't cache a query, or my looping over it and attaching to an email.